# Unable to showOpenDialog using electronjs and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I'm trying to create a simple desktop application using electronjs. My goal is open a `ShowOpenDialog`but for (unknown reason for me) it doesn't open nothing.
Tree view:

```
sample app
 |-index.html
 |-js
   |--jquery.js
   |--index.js
 |-main.js
 |-package.json
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <br />
    <button id="openFile">Open</button>
    <script>
        window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./js/jquery.js');
    </script>
    <sctipt src ="./js/index.js"></sctipt>
</html>
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#openFile").click(function(){
        dialog.showOpenDialog(function (fileNames) {
        }); 
    })    
})
```

main.js

```
'use strict';
const electron = require('electron');
const dialog = require('electron').dialog;
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

let mainWindow;

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
  mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
  mainWindow.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

And package.json

```
{
  "name": "electron-quick-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron main.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You require `dialog` in the main process, but try to use it in the renderer process. This can't work. You should either use the `remote` module to get a reference to the main process' `dialog` or use the `ipc` module to send a message to the main process to open the dialog.

As a minimal example, try to replace `dialog` in your index.js with `require('electron').remote.require('dialog')`; in the long run, however, I would suggest using IPC instead.

Answer (score 0):

you cant just threat renderer process as main process

you can use remote or use ipc like this

index.js

```
const electron = require("electron")
const ipc = electron.ipcRenderer

$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#openFile").click(function(){
        ipc.send("openF")
    })    
})
```

and in the main.js

add

```
const ipc = electron.ipcMain
ipc.on("openF", function(){
  const { dialog } = require('electron')
  dialog.showOpenDialog({title: "Open File",properties : ['openFile']}).then(result =>{
    mainWindow.webContents.send("filepaths", result.filePaths);

})
```

oh yea cus u need the filepath you will need this on index.js

```
ipcRenderer.on("filepaths", function(event, message) {
  if(message == undefined) return
  else{
    console.log(message); // Logs filepaths

    if(fl !== ""){
     console.log("no filepath found")
    }
}
// if you wanna open file use fs
})
```